# How to manage System.OutOfMemory and SQL timeout exceptions in RDLC reports

Tags: c#, exception, rdlc

I made an application that generates reports based on data from SQL database. The application works fine for reports with smaller number of entries, but in some cases I get the OutOfMemory exception or database timeout exception. My question is how can I manage these exceptions so that all of the data is correctly written into the report?
I'm using C# (in VS 2010) and RDLC reports in my application.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not really "handle" the exceptions to get all your data in your report.
You can tweak the timeouts but it won't get you very far.

Things you can do is prevent the exceptions :

- for OutOfMemoryException : you should not compute aggregates or do most of the computing report side. You may rely on views or on OLAP for the biggest part of the computing.
- for TimeOutException, same answer as for memory. But you should first rely on query optimization (indexes, query hints), as well as stored procedures instead of very complex (long to compile) dynamic queries

Comment: You were right, I simplified the query and now it executes in matter of seconds (I switched the data conversion part to the rdlc report itself)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do anything with `System.OutOfMemory` exception except add memory to you PC. To work with timeouts you can increase timeout.